# ORA-01722: invalid number while select numeric column and same numeric column reference in where

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select id 
from abc 
where id =  1001;
```

return invalid number.

1. abc is a view
2. datatype of id is number
3. In create view cast is used

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW abc AS 
SELECT CAST (SUBSTR(T_ID,3,100) AS NUMBER) AS ID
from TEST
```

4. id column has all numeric values only
5. `SELECT * FROM ABC` WORKS FINE AND SO insert query works

tried below code which returns nothing in dbms output

```
declare
  l_dummy number;
begin
  for cur in (select ID from abc)
  loop
     begin
        l_dummy := to_number(cur.ID);

     exception
        when others then dbms_output.put_line(cur.ID);
     end;
  end loop;
end;

column  datatype nullable
ID  NUMBER  Yes     1       NO  NO  NO

SELECT *
FROM abc
WHERE 
ID = 1001
```

returns:

> ```
> ORA-01722: invalid number
> 01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
> *Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
> *Action:   Specify a valid number.
> ```

Comment: Also select * from abc works fine.

Comment: If `ID` really is a `NUMBER` column that this error won't happen. Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below your question) and add the complete `create view` statement for the view in question and the `create table` statements for all tables used in the view (please [edit] your question do not post code in comments)

Comment: Obviously `T_ID` does not always contain valid numbers (where ever `t_id` comes from)

Comment: please clearly state the relationship between `abc` and `test`.

Comment: @RanjitBhingare Please stop adding additional information in comments. [Edit] your question instead.

Comment: Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems:

1. SUBSTR(T_ID,3,100) will not return number always -- We need to consider the only numeric query
2. If we apply anything in WHERE condition of the view, Order of the execution of the WHERE condition is the call of Oracle optimizer.

Please see below code:

```
-- Data preparation
create table TEST (T_ID varchar2(20));
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES('AB1000'); -- Good data
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES('AB1001'); -- Good data
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES('CD1001'); -- Good data
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES('XY1004'); -- Good data
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES('XYZ1004'); -- Bad data
```

--

```
-- Data in the table
SELECT * FROM TEST;
```

**Output**

[image]

```
-- You need to create your view as following
-- rownum is used so that WHERE clause of view is executed first 
-- and then any external WHERE clause on the view is executed 
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW ABC_NEWVIEW AS
    SELECT
        ID
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                CAST(SUBSTR(T_ID, 3, 100) AS NUMBER) AS ID,
                ROWNUM RN
            FROM
                TEST
            WHERE
                CASE
                    WHEN TRIM(TRANSLATE(SUBSTR(T_ID, 3, 100), '0123456789-,.', ' ')) IS NULL THEN 'numeric'
                    ELSE 'alpha'
                END = 'numeric'
        )
```

--

```
-- View
SELECT * FROM ABC_NEWVIEW
```

**Output**

[image]

```
-- Query using WHERE condition
SELECT *
FROM ABC_NEWVIEW
WHERE 
ID = 1001
```

**Output**

[image]

You can find the demo in the following link:

[DB Fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=78933d8aba693e1e8c3c2d81c0aa2c8d)

You can see the demo of VIEW without ROWNUM:
[Reproduced your issue](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5af20df71c6297ea3f3d7220064a6ac6)  -- So the issue is the order of the execution.

Cheers!!